How to override compiler flags from cross file by my own flags put into Meson script?
I'm trying to ask here because the Meson community does not respond (my original post there: https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/discussions/13531)
I have a question about compiler flags (c_args, cpp_args) in the Meson scripts.
The flags can be set in a crossfile, for example:
[binaries] 
c = ['gcc', '-some_flag=0']

Other possibility is to set the flags in [built-in options] of the same crossfile:
[built-in options] 
c_args = ['-some_flag=1']

And then I can set these flags directly in a meson script:
c_args = ['-some_flag=2']

executable('my_app', 'main.c', c_args: c_args)

If I define these flags together as above then the compile command generated by Meson will be (simplified):
gcc -some_flag=0 -some_flag=2 -some_flag=1

I'd expect the flag set in the meson script ('-some_flag=2') to be at the end of the compile command and thus override the definitions from the cross file. Is there some good reason that the flags from [built-in options] are at the end of the compile command?
I'm asking because I'm using some community crossfile that I cannot change. This crossfile has some flags in [built-in options] and I need to override some of the flags in my own meson script. But the Meson puts the flags from [built-in options] at the end of the compile command and thus overrides my flags defined in my meson script.
